# apm update: error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: atom-editor

Recently, I tried re-installing vim-mode-plus on atom, and when that didn't work I decided to run `apm update` to ensure my package manager for atom was up to date. I am getting the error:

`Unable to download https://www.atom.io/api/packages/vim-mode-plus/versions/1.31.0/tarball: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I am assuming this has to do with my corporate proxy, how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  I've set strict-ssl=false and my proxy info in ~/.atom/apmrc  and still can't search to install packages.

Answer (score 6):

Answers taken from - https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#proxy-and-firewall-settings

Consult above link for addtional information.

If you are behind a firewall, this command may help:

```
apm config set strict-ssl false
```

If you are using a proxy, this command may help:

```
apm config set https-proxy <your-corporate-proxy>
```